# Json starting with [ and when using json_encode it starts with " in magento2 using php7.1

Tags: php, arrays, json, php-7.1, magento-2.3

I want my json to start with { but if using json_encode it is getting converted into string, I am using php7.1 on ubuntu and working on magento 2.3

This is what I am getting with the below code, I don't want '['

```
[
    {
        "success": "true",
        "data": {
            "mainimages": [
                {
```

Here is my code

```
$response = array(
    array(
        "success" => "true",
        "data" => $alldata,
        "newarrivalheading" => "NEW ARRIVALS",
        "instagramheading" => "CELEBS IN LULU",
        "specialpriceheading" => "SPECIAL PRICES",
        "editorwishlistheading" => "EDITOR'S WISHLIST",
        "stylehighlightheading" => "STYLE HIGHLIGHTS",
        "styletagline" => "#Looks to swipe right",
        "newarrivalindex" => 3,
        "instagramindex" => 9,
        "editorwishlistviewall" => "",
        "sliderimage" => $sliderimage
    )
);      
return $response;
```

This is what I want

```
 {
        "success": "true",
        "data": {
            "mainimages": [
                {
```

Comment: Sooo, `json_encode($response[0])`? Or just get rid of the outer `array()`?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard I am still facing issue, so once it is fixed i will accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So remove the unnecessary outer array like so

```
$alldata = [1,2,3,4];
$sliderimage = ['xz.jpg','ab.png'];

$response = array(
               "success" => "true",
               "data" => $alldata,
               "newarrivalheading" => "NEW ARRIVALS",
               "instagramheading" => "CELEBS IN LULU",
               "specialpriceheading" => "SPECIAL PRICES",
               "editorwishlistheading" => "EDITOR'S WISHLIST",
               "stylehighlightheading" => "STYLE HIGHLIGHTS",
               "styletagline" => "#Looks to swipe right",
               "newarrivalindex" => 3,
               "instagramindex" => 9,
               "editorwishlistviewall" => "",
               "sliderimage" => $sliderimage
        );
echo json_encode($response);
```

RESULT

```
    {
    "success": "true",
    "data": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ],
    "newarrivalheading": "NEW ARRIVALS",
    "instagramheading": "CELEBS IN LULU",
    "specialpriceheading": "SPECIAL PRICES",
    "editorwishlistheading": "EDITOR'S WISHLIST",
    "stylehighlightheading": "STYLE HIGHLIGHTS",
    "styletagline": "#Looks to swipe right",
    "newarrivalindex": 3,
    "instagramindex": 9,
    "editorwishlistviewall": "",
    "sliderimage": [
        "xz.jpg",
        "ab.png"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly Thanks for the reply the thing is $sliderimage is also in array, so now I am getting somthing    "styletagline": "#Looks to swipe right",
    "newarrivalindex": 3,
    "instagramindex": 9,
    "editorwishlistviewall": "",
    "sliderimage": ""
}[]

Comment: Unless I missed something, that should not make much difference, I changed the answer to change `$sliderimage = ['xz.jpg','ab.png'];` into an array

Comment: I am getting [] at the end of my json.

Comment: My code does not, so obviously you are doing something that I am not

Comment: Your code `returns` the `$response` and therefore converts it to JSON somehere else. What do you do with this response after it is returned?? That is likely where your issue is